# Is the word after 'footwear' in this sentence correct? Should it stay 'enhance' or should it be 'enhances'?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

The sentence is this:

Take time to explore how your beautifully crafted footwear enhance your every moment.

This doesn't read comfortably to me and I feel that it should be 'enhances'.

Which is correct? I am proofreading a document and I am aware that 'footwear' can be the plural form, too. Would that mean that 'enhance' is then correct, even if it doesn't seem to read correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware that 'footwear' can be the plural form,

No. "footwear" is uncountable and thus takes a singular verb

See

[Oxford Learners' Dicitionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/footwear)/ˈfʊtwɛr/ 
[uncountable]

things that people wear on their feet, for example shoes and boots Be sure to wear the correct footwear to prevent injuries to your feet.

Comment: Thank you so much. Where I was looking, it stated that footwear was countable and uncountable which confused me. Much prefer your resource.